# Mistake in validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Something is wrong with my validation. Data from the form is created and I can see it when I use the dd() function. But when it comes to creating and sending that data to the database it creates an empty row. My Laravel version is 8.83.17. Here's my route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth.amicms'])->name('amicms.')->prefix('amicms')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class);
});
```

Here's the request:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name_en' => 'required',
            'body_en' => 'required',
            'name_ua' => 'required',
            'body_ua' => 'required',
            'name_ru' => 'required',
            'body_ru' => 'required',
            'meta_title_en' => 'string',
            'meta_description_en' => 'string',
            'meta_keywords_en' => 'string',
            'meta_title_ua' => 'string',
            'meta_description_ua' => 'string',
            'meta_keywords_ua' => 'string',
            'meta_title_ru' => 'string',
            'meta_description_ru' => 'string',
            'meta_keywords_ru' => 'string',
            'image' => 'required|image',
            'price' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required'
        ];
    }
```

Here's the model:

```
protected $fillable = ['name_en, body_en, name_ua, body_ua, name_ru, body_ru,
    meta_title_en, meta_description_en, meta_keywords_en, meta_title_ua, meta_description_ua, meta_keywords_ua,
    meta_title_ru, meta_description_ru, meta_keywords_ru, image, price, status'];
```

Here's the controller

```
public function store(StorePostRequest $request)
    {

        $input = $request->all();
        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
            $imageDestinationPath = 'uploads/';
            $postImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $image->move($imageDestinationPath, $postImage);
            $input['image'] = "$postImage";
        }
        Post::create($input);

         return view ('amicms.posts.index', ['layout' => $this->layout]);
    }
```

Here's the view:

```
form action="{{ route('amicms.posts.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Языковая версия</label>
                                    <select id="language" class="custom-select"
                                            name="language" required>
                                        <option value="ru">Русский</option>
                                        <option value="ua">Украинский</option>
                                        <option value="en">English</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Статус</label>
                                    <select class="custom-select @if($errors->has('status')) noty_type_error @endif"
                                        name="status" id="" required>
                                        <option value="1">Published</option>
                                        <option value="0">Not Published</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        @php($formLang = ['ru', 'ua', 'en'])
                        @for($i=0; $i<3;$i++)
                            <div id="build-form-{{ $formLang[$i] }}" class="d-none">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Name (<span class="text-uppercase">{{ $formLang[$i] }}</span>)</label>
                                            <input name="name_{{ $formLang[$i] }}" type="text" placeholder=""
                                                   class="form-control @if($errors->has('name_ru')) noty_type_error @endif">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Full description of the entry (<span class="text-uppercase">{{ $formLang[$i] }}</span>)</label>
                                            <textarea class="form-control @if($errors->has('body')) noty_type_error @endif"
                                                      name="body_{{ $formLang[$i] }}" id="summernote"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Meta Title (<span class="text-uppercase">{{ $formLang[$i] }}</span>)</label>
                                            <input name="meta_title_{{ $formLang[$i] }}" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Meta Keywords (<span class="text-uppercase">{{ $formLang[$i] }}</span>)</label>
                                            <input name="meta_keywords_{{ $formLang[$i] }}" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Meta Description (<span class="text-uppercase">{{ $formLang[$i] }}</span>)</label>
                                            <input name="meta_description_{{ $formLang[$i] }}" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        @endfor

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Photo</label>
                                    <input name="image" type="file" placeholder="" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Price</label>
                                    <input name="price" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="text-right mrg-top-5">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Here's the migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name_en')->nullable();
            $table->text('body_en')->nullable();
            $table->string('name_ru')->nullable();
            $table->text('body_ru')->nullable();
            $table->string('name_ua')->nullable();
            $table->text('body_ua')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_title_en')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_description_en')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_keywords_en')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_title_ru')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_description_ru')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_keywords_ru')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_title_ua')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_description_ua')->nullable();
            $table->text('meta_keywords_ua')->nullable();
            $table->string('image');
            $table->decimal('price', 10, 2);
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Where are you actually calling the validator?  Typically this is done inside the controller but I don't see any code for it.

Comment: Show your migration file.

Comment: @Erich It would be called by default with the injection in `function store(StorePostRequest $request)`

Comment: Ah I missed the typehint there.  Thanks.

Comment: You could do `$post = Post::create($input);` and then `dd($post)`. What does it return? Nothing obvious in your laravel.log? You might also want to show any validation errors, as posted in [Displaying The Validation Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Comment: (Probably not related) You have fields in your `$fillable` that don't show up anywhere (`meta_name_*`, `meta_body_*`) and fields in your validation that don't show up in `$fillable` (`meta_title_*`, 'meta_description_*`)

Comment: @brombeer the only attributes dd($post) returns is. the created_at, updated_at and id fields for some reason

Comment: Your `$fillable` attribute needs to have the fields individually quoted as multiple array values, not quoted as a whole single string. `'name_en', 'body_en', 'name_ua',...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  protected $fillable = [
    'name_en','body_en','name_ua','body_ua','name_ru',' body_ru','meta_title_en','meta_description_en','meta_keywords_en','meta_title_ua','meta_description_ua','meta_keywords_ua','meta_title_ru','meta_description_ru','meta_keywords_ru','image','price','status'
    ];
```